# In C (also C++), how '&' operator works as both address operator and bitwise operator ? As operator overloading is not supported by C

Tags: c++, c, operator-overloading, bitwise-operators, address-operator

The operator '&' can be used in both of following way  `int a; scanf("%d",&a);`
and `printf("%d",1&2)`.
But different behaviour (for first as address operator and second time as bit-wise operator).
I know operator overloading is not there in C. Then how it works ?. Also highlight for c++.

Comment: It works by being defined differently as a unary and as a binary operator in the language specs

Comment: There are *many* operators that have different meaning in different context. And C differs from C++ here because the `&` "operator" can be used for different things in C++ than from C. Not to mention overloading of the operators in C++ which doesn't exist in C.

Comment: So are they are also separately defined for unary and for binary in C++ ?

Comment: Thanks a lot for nice explanation.@Someprogrammerdude

Comment: Thanks for nice explanation. @SamiKuhmonen

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Why did you put "operator" in quotation marks? AFAIK it's officially stated as operator.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio Because the ampersand can be used in other places than as an operator. For example in declarations (in C++).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude Ahh, Yes, I mentioned references too, but didn't knew that when part of a declaration, it isn't an unary operator.

Comment: @RobertSsupportsMonicaCellio It might just be me using a more old-fashioned terminology.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In "C" language, operators have different meaning when they are used as prefix to expression, suffix to expression or "infix" (between two expressions).

Consider '*', which performs multiplication as 'infix' operator, and pointer indirection when used as a prefix. Similarily, the '-' operator, which performs subtraction as 'infix' operator, and negation when used as a prefix.

Basically, it's not about overriding, it if the operator appears between two expressions, or as a  prefix to a single expression.

In the same way, The "C" compiler knows if the '&' is bit-wise and, or address-of, based on it's position is the expression: If it is between two expressions, it's the AND, if it is before an expression, it is 'address-of'.

See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Infix_notation about infix.

Comment: You could also add that `*` means "declare as pointer" when used in declarations. So it's not only used as an operator in expressions.

Answer (score 6):

> I know operator overloading is not there in C.

This is incorrect. `a + b` performs integer addition if `a` and `b` are integers, floating-point addition if `a` and `b` are floating-point numbers, and pointer arithmetic if `a` or `b` is a pointer.

C has operator overloading built into the language. It does not support custom operator overloading defined by the program.

In the case of `&` being an operator for taking an address and for performing a bitwise AND, the distinction is made by the language grammar. The `&` for taking an address can appear only applied to a *cast-expression* in the grammar. The `&` for bitwise AND can appear only after an *AND-expression* and before an *equality-expression*. These “tokens” (*cast-expression*, *AND-expression*, and *equality-expression*) may be unfamiliar to you, but they are formally defined in the grammar for the C language, and, as the compiler is parsing source code, it recognizes the structure of expressions and matches the source code to the tokens of the grammar. This is also true for C++ except for a minor technical difference: In C++, one of the tokens is *and-expression* instead of *AND-expression*.

The definition of the grammar is such that recognition of these tokens always uniquely distinguishes how the `&` operator is being used.

Answer (score 1):

C does not support operator overloading (beyond what it built into the language).
As you can see in this Wikipedia [Operators in C](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operators_in_C_and_C%2B%2B)

The Address-of ("address of a")     "**&a**" is defined as R* K::operator &();
whereas

The Bitwise AND     "**a & b**" is defined as R K::operator &(S b);

So basically the "&" operator has different meaning when used as a unary operator and as a binary operator operator. The same goes for various other operators like, "*****" , "**-**", etc.

Answer (score 0):

It has simple different meanings when applied to the lvalue (it the unary operator in this case) or when it is used in the math expression with two operands.

Answer (score 0):

> "The operator `&` can be used in **both** of following way `int a; scanf("%d",&a);` and `printf("%d",1&2)`."

Note that in the case of C++ you forgot another important third use. The `&` operator can also be used to declare [*references*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reference_(C%2B%2B)).

```
int x = 24;
int& r_x = x;
```

Answer (score 0):

the language divides operators based on its operands first. In one category itself overloading can be in-built. **Your example is about the first division**. Address-of is a unary operator and bitwise-AND is a binary operator. when you write operator function in c++ you will see the difference of these two categories.
Operator overloading is inbuilt to languages. example simple arithmetic addition operator. it can work with simple one-byte integer data as well as float (significant & exponent). Basically it is there with maths. so while making C language, they just translated those into functionality. In C specification, you cannot find overloading as a keyword for this behavior. According to them, after formula expression, anything has to be expressed as different functions. Each function should be named based on the functionality that it offers. When C++ introduced an opportunity to create new types, operators with its basic n-nary form allowed to operate with new types. In a nutshell, C's philosophy was different.